# Push into array of objects with nested level using spread operator

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I am having an object containing array of objects with following format which is stored in a state

```
const [value, setVal] = useState({ available : [], done: [] })
```

`done` is an array of objects with following structure

```
[{col: "test", val: ["abc","xyz"]}]
```

I am writing a function that takes `field` and `value` as input parameters. If the field is present in `done` array, then I need to push it inside its corresponding `val` array. Else I need to create a new object and then push it inside. How can I achieve this?

How can I set the state in both the cases?Code that I tried is below

```
function update(field, value){
    const filterIndex = value.done.findIndex((obj) => field === obj.col);
    if (filterIndex > -1) {
      value.done[filterIndex].val.push(value);
    } else {
      setVal({
        ...value,
        done: [
          ...value.done,
          {
            col: field,
            val: [value],
          }
        ]
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you split the `val` into multiple states. It's too "nested" for a single useState imo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a separate variable name for the state instead of `value` since the function has a local variable also called `value`.

Try like below.

```
const [values, setVals] = useState({ available: [], done: [] })

function update(field, value) {
  const filterIndex = values.done.findIndex((obj) => field === obj.col);
  if (filterIndex > -1) {
    // get a copy of the previous state done values
    const updatedDone = [...values.done];
    // update the new value in the copy of the array
    updatedDone[filterIndex].val.push(value);
    // update the state
    setVals((prevValue) => ({ ...prevValue, done: updatedDone }));
  } else {
    // add the new entry for the new filed with the value
    setVals((prevValue) => ({
      ...prevValue,
      done: [
        ...prevValue.done,
        {
          col: field,
          val: [value],
        },
      ],
    }));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This may be one possible solution:

**Code Snippet**

```js
const stateVal = { available : [], done: [{col: "test", val: ["abc","xyz"]}] };

const updateStateVal = (sv, field, value) => ({
  ...sv,
  done: (
    sv.done.map(ob => ob.col).includes(field)
    ? sv.done.map(ob => (
      ob.col === field
      ? {...ob, val: ob.val.concat([value])}
      : {...ob}
    ))
    : sv.done.concat([{ col: field, val: [value] }])
  )
});

console.log('existing col test: ', updateStateVal(stateVal, 'test', 'def'));
console.log('non-exist col test2: ', updateStateVal(stateVal, 'test2', 'def'));
```

**How to use**

```
setVal(prev => ({...updateStateVal(prev, field, value)}));
```

**Explanation**

- The objective is to insert `value` based on presence/absence of `field` in `done`.
- The method `updateStateVal` takes 3 params, the prev-state `sv`, the `field` & the `value`
- Use `...` spread operator to list down all props of prev (ie, `sv`) as-is
- Now, override the `done` prop
- First check if the prev-state's `done` already has `field` by matching with the `col`s from each array-element.
- This is done using `.map()` in conjunction with `.includes()`
- If found, iterate through the `done` array.

  For the array element where `col` matches `field`, `.concat` the existing `val` array with `value`. All other elements go as-is.
- If not found, simply `.concat` a single-element array (`[{ col: field, val: [value]}]`) to existing `done` array.